# Can cPanel listen on all domains on a dedicated IP?

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a large number of clients (affiliates) that need to make CNAMEs so they use their own domain to display the content of a website hosted on cpanel.

This must be done instantly without human intervention of adding addon domains.

On nginx, I could easily create a default_server that listens to any domain on that IP. Is it possible to do this on WHM/Cpanel? they have a dedicated machine.

Comment: cPanel is a front end in front of Apache for managing shared hosting.   I'm not sure that cPanel lets you configure the default site for Apache, but Apache can certainly handle that.  Do you need a solution that has to be configured through cPanel, or could you configure Apache more directly?

Comment: Also, how would you handle Https certs?

Comment: @davidgo they use Cloudflare which gives them a free cert (it acts as a proxy, the connection between cloudflare and my server can be with a self signed/invalid cert)... anyway I think it's not possible with cpanel, I'll have to migrate to an unmanaged system

Comment: I would have thought you should be able to do this through WHM (not necessarily cPanel). What currently happens when you request the server's IP address? Yes, cPanel is often used in shared server environments, but it can also be used to manage dedicated servers (as in this case). https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/tip-overriding-the-default-apache-virtualhost.234362/

Comment: @MrWhite When I request the ip address, it redirects to /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi with a cpanel "SORRY!" message